# How to get all links posted by user by fql?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I need to get all links posted only by user on his time line.
I tried `SELECT caption, title, picture, url, via_id, privacy FROM link WHERE owner= me()`. But it displays links posted by other applications. How to get this from `fql`?